# CSS3 Image Hover doesn't work on IE 10 and 11, Latest Chrome and Safari

Tags: html, css, hover

I am trying to create a CSS3 Image hover however for some reason it won't work on IE 10 and 11, Latest Chrome and Safari. Kinda wondering if there's a trick or tip to force it to run?

Here's the HTML:

```
<ul class="demo-3">
    <li>
        <figure>
            <img src="images/image1.jpg" alt=""/>
            <figcaption>
                <h2>This is a cool title!</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nost.</p>
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Here's the CSS:

```
.demo-3 {
    position:relative;
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    overflow:hidden;
    float:left;
    margin-right:20px
}
.demo-3 figure {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    position:relative;
    cursor:pointer;
    margin-left:-50px
}
.demo-3 figure img {
    display:block;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    margin:-15px 0
}
.demo-3 figure figcaption {
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:5;
    -webkit-box-sizing:border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing:border-box;
    box-sizing:border-box
}
.demo-3 figure h2 {
    font-family:'Lato';
    color:#fff;
    font-size:20px;
    text-align:left
}
.demo-3 figure p {
    display:block;
    font-family:'Lato';
    font-size:12px;
    line-height:18px;
    margin:0;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:left
}
.demo-3 figure figcaption {
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    padding:29px 44px;
    background-color:rgba(26,76,110,0.5);
    text-align:center;
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(-180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(-180deg);
    transform:rotateY(-180deg);
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s
}
.demo-3 figure img {
    backface-visibility:hidden;
    -webkit-transition:all .5s;
    -moz-transition:all .5s;
    transition:all .5s
}
.demo-3 figure:hover img,figure.hover img {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(180deg);
    transform:rotateY(180deg)
}
.demo-3 figure:hover figcaption,figure.hover figcaption {
    -webkit-transform:rotateY(0);
    -moz-transform:rotateY(0);
    transform:rotateY(0)
}
```

JSFIDDLE HERE: http://jsfiddle.net/nybsdqar/1/

Any idea what's hindering this why it wont work on the said browsers?

Comment: Works in 10 and 11 for me.

Comment: works in chrome fine

Comment: How about it SAFARI?